# Proving that involves set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

**A**,**B** are **subsets** of **C**. Prove that **A** ⊂**B** ⇔ **C-B**⊂**C-A**.

P.S. I've already accomplish proving it forward (If A then B) but I'm stuck on proving it backwards (If B then A). This is what I've tried:
Assume C-B ⊂ C-A, let x ∈ C-B then x∈C and x∉B →x∈C and x∉B.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Assume not: there is $x$ such that $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that the assumption of $C\smallsetminus B\subseteq C\smallsetminus A$ entails that, for any $x$, $x\in A\to x\in B$.

So assume $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ with the aim of deriving a contradiction.

Remember to make use of the premises.

- Premise $A\subseteq C$
- Premise $B\subseteq C$

  - Assume $C\smallsetminus B\subseteq C\smallsetminus A$.

    - Take an arbitrary $x$.

      - Assume $x\in A$.

        - Assume $x\notin B$
        - (some derivation happens here)
        - $\bot$ (Contradiction)
      - $x\in B$
    - $x \in A\to x\in B$
  - $A\subseteq B$
- $C\smallsetminus B\subseteq C\smallsetminus A~\to~A\subseteq B$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $C-B$ is a proper subset of $C-A$. Let $a$ be an element of $A$. Then $a$ is not an element of $C-A$. Since $C-B$ is a subset of $C-A$, $a$ is not an element of $C-B$, thus is an element of $B$. This shows that $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Since $C-B$ is a proper subset of $C-A$, there exists an element $c$ of $C-A$ which is not an element of $C-B$, that is, there exists an element $c$ of $B$ which is not an element of $A$; thus $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first part, from
C - B proper subset C - A,
conclude
B = C - (C - B) proper subset C - (C - A)  = A.